# Closing Laptop Lid Issue

Tags: 13.10, laptop, suspend, fan

I boot up ubuntu, and log in.
I close my Laptop lid, it goes into suspend (this is what I want)
I open it up, and log back in, fan turns off (not sure why)
I try to close it again, but no suspend
After about a minute, fan comes on full blast

The laptop stays this way, full fan, and unable to suspend when closing the lid until I reboot.

I'm using a Toshiba Satellite L505D-S5965, and have ubuntu 13.10 64bit installed.
I also tried this with the 32 bit version of 12.04LTE
Please help

Answer (score 0):

you should've kept this to your original post: [Suspend only works once on Toshiba Satellite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378024/issue-with-suspend/378033#378033) take a look at this post: [Closing lid does not suspend laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70140/closing-lid-does-not-suspend-laptop)